# Problems with Guice late bindings / assisted injects

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have some code that looks like this (simplified):

```
public Reader newInstance(Catalog catalog) {
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper(catalog);
    return new Reader(mapper)
}

public main() {
    // expensive operation
    Catalog catalog = readCatalogFromDatabase();

    Reader reader = Reader.newInstance(catalog);
    // do stuff with reader
}
```

How can I redesign this so that I still create Catalog, but Guice creates Reader and Mapper? I tried using assisted injections, but since Catalog isn't a direct dependency of Reader, I can't figure out how to get a factory method that accepts a catalog object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Have Guice bind your Catalog. This may mean passing the Catalog instance into your Module, but Modules can take any number of constructor arguments, so that's no problem. In your module this will look like:

   ```
   bind(Catalog.class).toInstance(myVeryExpensiveCatalog);
   ```
2. If you really need to create a Reader based on an unknown or changeable instance of Catalog, then your hunch is right to use assisted injection. This is how I would make it look:

   ```
   class Reader {
     interface Factory {
       Reader create(Catalog catalog);
     }

     @Inject Reader(@Assisted Catalog catalog, OtherDependency etc) {
       this.catalog = catalog;
     }
   }

   class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
     @Override public void configure() {
       install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(Reader.Factory.class));
     }
   }
   ```

   Then you can just inject `Reader.Factory` and get your reader by calling `readerFactory.create(catalog);`. Note that `create` can be named anything, and the `Factory` can be in any location with any name--those are just the names and locations I prefer.

Now, in the [AssistedInject documentation](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) you'll see that they also call `implement`. You'll only need to do this if `Reader` is an interface, so Guice knows what kind of concrete class to build to satisfy `create`'s return type.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this helps! I did the first thing you suggested, but then I have to create a new (child) injector with the module. I wasn't sure if that was the right way to go. 2. doesn't really work, as Catalog is used in Mapper, and Mapper is used in Reader. Catalog is not a direct dependency for Reader, but needed to create a Mapper.

Comment: Oh okay. I suppose you could do the same--have a `Reader.Factory` that receives a Catalog, which passes along to a `Mapper.Factory` that receives a Catalog, but that starts to defeat the point of dependency injection. You're trying to specify the way 2nd level dependencies are constructed, so creating a child injector seems reasonable. BTW, a cop-out solution would be to create a holder object, like `class CatalogHolder { Catalog catalog; }` and bind that as a Singleton to make it accessible after the Catalog creation. I prefer child injectors over global state, but your opinion may differ. :)